# Beginner: console ">" changes into "+"

Tags: r

This is my first time posting on stackoverflow! This is probably a very silly and elementary question, but I've not been able to find an answer to it. When I type in this function into the R console:

```
> wd <- function(directory) {
+     setwd("~/CourseraDataScience/RProgramming/"&directory&""")
+   }
```

I am stuck with a "+" instead of a ">" symbol in the console, and everything I type doesn't appear to do anything. I'm not sure what this is called and how to get back to inputting stuff into R, except for restarting it. Can someone kindly explain this to me?

My goal here is to create a function that allows me to indicate the location of CSV files for data analysis, but I am quite stuck as you can see. Any help would be great!

Comment: You should probably read the intro manual http://cran.r-project.org/manuals.html

Comment: You have syntax errors and unmatched quotation marks... +1 for Richard Scriven's advice.

Comment: If this happens, you don't need to restart R. Just hit the esc key.

Comment: I think it can come from unmatched parenthesis or quotation.  Happens to me all the time...  I didn't know about the esc key solution.

Comment: Thanks so much, guys. I'm really impressed with all the replies. This is a wonderful community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually a `+` means that your code is not finished. You do not need to create a function for locating your datas. The following code is enough

```
setwd("C:/CourseraDataScience/RProgramming/")
```

You can create directly a related R project within the needed directory and thus `setwd` function will not be required anymore.