# Rename vector with conditions

Tags: r

There is a vector which looks like this

```
v <- c(2,5,8,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,4,3,35,7)
```

Is there a way I can transform these levels into

```
A,A1,A1,A1,A1,A1,A1,A1,A1,A1,A1,A1,A2,A1
```

I know that I can use if commands like `if(v < 2){out <- 'A'}`, `if(v < 10){out <- 'A1'}` and `if(v > 10){out <- 'A2'}`

but this is very slow as my vector has nearly a million numbers. Is there a way to do this really fast? Ideally I would be able to set a variable containing all numbers for which A should be the replacement, a var for which A1 should be the replacement, and so on.

Comment: I feel like this exact question is being [asked five times a day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27919791/convert-numerical-variable-into-factor). Is this some type of new Coursera assignment?

Comment: Coursera is definitely [back in session](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002343/beginner-console-changes-into).

Comment: Why you don't edit your question ? You should also accept a solution ( regarding all your previous question you have never accept a solution , maybe you should read how SO is working).  People here Try to help you (Akrun for example give you at least 3 solutions) but the minimum is to ask a clear question and to accept a solution one it satisfies your requirement.

Answer (score 4):

You can try `cut`

```
as.character(cut(v, breaks=c(0,2,10,Inf),
                labels=c('A', 'A1', 'A2')))
#[1] "A"  "A1" "A1" "A1" "A1" "A1" "A1" "A1" "A1" "A1" "A1" "A1" "A2" "A1"
```

Or `findInterval` (which would be faster)

```
 c('A', 'A1', 'A2')[findInterval(v, c(0,2.1, 10, Inf))]
```

#### Update

If the values to be replaced do not follow any specific pattern and is decided based on your own set rules, then create a vector of unique values from the "v" and name it based on the values you need to replace, and use `[` to get a faster replacement for the entire vector.

```
unname(setNames( c('A', 'A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A2', 'A1'),
   unique(v))[as.character(v)])
#[1] "A"  "A1" "A1" "A1" "A1" "A1" "A1" "A1" "A1" "A1" "A1" "A1" "A2" "A1"
```

#### Update2

Based on the OP's comments to @agstudy's post, if the values to be replaced are stored in a couple of vectors, a possible `data.table` solution would be as below.  It is assumed that the corresponding values in "q" vector that matches the "v" should be replaced by "A", those in "w" replaced by "A1", and the rest of the values as "A2".  Here, I create a `data.table` using `setDT` on a list of "v", and a vector "V2" which is preset with "A2".  Set the "V1" column as key (`setkey`) , join "q", assign the corresponding "V2" values as "A", and similarly for "w".

```
q <- c(3,7,6,9,8)
w <- c(4,14)
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(list(v, V2=rep('A2', length(v)))), 
            V1)[J(q), V2:='A'][J(w), V2:='A1']$V2
 #[1] "A2" "A"  "A1" "A2" "A2" "A"  "A"  "A"  "A"  "A"  "A"  "A"  "A"  "A2"
```

Comment: the problem is that in the data there are no limits as here...it can be that 0-8 is A, then 9 is A1 and 10 is A again. This is why I thought setting a variable for all values which are associated with A, A1 and so....

Comment: @wery Then perhaps you need to recode those based on the values.

Comment: dont really understand what you mean could you maye give an example?

Comment: i was really looking for something which could do something like: if element i of the vector is 2,8,9,7,6 then replace with A1; if it is 10,3 or 100 replace with A2...but just without the if statements in a 1liner or something..

Comment: your solution relies on the values being pefectly sorted from 1 to 10 only from 11 to...A2 and further...

Comment: @wery That was basically what my solution does.  No, my solution does not rely on being sorted from 1 to 10.  It is based on the how you name the unique(v).

Comment: @wery I guess your comments were based on the original solution.  Please check if the update helps.

Answer (score 2):

Using the vectorized `ifelse`, this should be faster (at least for the given example):

```
ifelse(v < 2 ,'A',ifelse(v < 10, 'A1', 'A2'))
[1] "A1" "A1" "A1" "A1" "A1" "A1" "A1" "A1" "A1" "A1" "A1" "A1" "A2" "A1"
```

#### more generally (after comments):

```
ifelse(v %in% vA ,'A',ifelse(v %in% vA1, 'A1', 'A2'))
```

where `vA` and `vA1` are some vectors, for example :

```
vA <- c(3,7,6,9,8)
vA1 <- c(4)
```

Comment: Based on the comments to my post,  `A` could replace 10

Comment: is there no possibility to say that if the number in the vector is say 3,7,6,9,8 (stored as var (call it q) then it should replace A: if it is 4 and 14 it should store it as A1 (where 4 and 14 are stored in w) something like this!!!

Comment: @Wery I edit my answer , but please edit your question to precise this.